# Drupal - Filter Nodes Retrieve by views module according to an array of categories

Tags: drupal

I have a array of taxonomies ids.
I created a page using views module.
I just want to use Contextual filtering to retrieve nodes that their taxonomy  references s id are in this array. For example:

```
term_taxonomy_ids = array ( 135, 195, 253, 469, 987, 6975 );
```

I want to retrieve nodes that their taxonomy references ids are in this array.

Comment: Contextual or conceptual filtering? What's conceptual filtering?

Comment: Contextual Filtering :) sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a relationship from the node to the taxonomy through the  taxonomy reference field that you have on the node.

Then create a contextual filter of type "Term ID" and using your relationship that you just created.

In the section "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE" select "Provide default value" you can then past your values in there or use php to retrieve them.

The last thing to do, under more at the bottom of the page, select "Allow multiple values"

Comment: Where are you getting your array of taxonomie ids from? What is significant about them?

Comment: with function variable_set i made that array and with variable_get i get the array

Comment: Select php under provide default values as stated above the use variable_get to get your array and return it using something like this: return implode('+',$tid_array);